# Setting different LaunchImage in LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I've got a set of LaunchImages in various sizes in my Assets.xcassets folder. I've created it by right-clicking in `Assets.xcassets -> App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS Launch Image`, and put all the differently sized images inside every box.

iPads with 9.7" (or more) screen size need to have a different launch image from the iPhones.

I've been using `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to display the LaunchImage, with proper constraints. But only the iPhone version is displayed on the Simulator (and badly strecthed out).

[image: My LaunchScreen.storyboard]

Is there any way to make iOS choose the proper LaunchImage from the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `LaunchScreen.storyboard` has issues with using `.launchimage` image sets, but not with `.imageset` extension.

I've resolved it by not using the `.launchimage` file in `Assets.xcassets`, but by creating a `New Image Set`, and then just using two resolution files, one for iPhones and one for iPads.